# Send ArrayBuffer over datachannel: DOM Exception 12

Tags: javascript, dom, binary-data, webrtc, arraybuffer

I'm trying to send some data over a datachannel between two browsers.
In my code I have:

```
var asString = JSON.stringify(this);
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(asString.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
var bufView = new Uint16Array(buffer);
for (var i=0; i<asString.length; i++) {
    bufView[i] = asString.charCodeAt(i);
}

channel.send(buffer);
```

In this example, datachannel is open and correctly working (its type is WebKitDatachannel).
When I send it, i receive this exception:

```
Uncaught Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: use:  channel.send(JSON.stringify(buffer));

Comment: I have some problem about message size limitation: datachannel does not allow me to send messages bigger than ~1100 chars.

Comment: Yeah, you're right...I also send 900 characters when I transfer files...well, datachannel is currently slow regardless of how much channels you open. If I send a message after 30ms, it works....but for larger messages, time interval must be bigger.

Comment: so this limitation exists, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, .. in this moment: slow speed, limited message size....and only unreliable streams are supported on chrome.

Comment: You can test my file sharing app here... it is slow... http://p2p-share.tk/ .. I send message packets after each 500ms.....otherwise it fails to transfer 100% accurate data(file)....

Comment: Remember, only one channel works at a time...you can create many channels but you can't use them at the same time. Otherwise, other peer will not receive your message.

Comment: You should try DataChannels in Mozilla nightly (or Aurora). (in about:config flip media.peerconnection.enabled).   The largest file I've sent to myself with dc.send(file_blob); is ~270MB; took a minute or so.  Full underlying SCTP support, multiple channels, reliable, unreliable, etc.  Chrome will be updating to comply with the draft spec sometime soon.

Comment: Good comment sir. I really want chrome to support SCTP in realtime. Also reliable "ordered" messages. It would be awesome to share files over many channels using "webkit" RTC-DataChannels!

Comment: Thank you @jesup, I'll try it (even with this enormous delay)!

Comment: @b3by - Both FF and Chrome support SCTP datachannels now.

Comment: Always failed on Chrome M40, I got an error "DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel': Could not send data" no matter how big the arraybuffer.